# Calculate 3D Object's size inside Canvas

Tags: unity-game-engine

On this forum [3D Objects inside Canvas](https://forum.unity.com/threads/3d-objects-inside-canvas.266145/)

I have fallowed #9 replied by pavlito

pavlito just said "Increase model's scale to something like 100, 100, 100"

But i wonder, How to find model's scale that make the 3d Object has specific size on the canvas like width = 160, height = 50? I want to make a 3d Object ui has exactly the same width and height as a RectTransform Object (Button).

Thank you.

Edit :

You will see a 3d cube and a ui button in a Canvas, and canvas inspector window on the right.
[image]

Here is the cube inspector, i already scale it to 100, 100, 100. But i do not know size of it on the canvas. I want to know how to calculate it.

And my purpose is calculate scale of the cube that make its width and height to be the same value of the button on the left(150 * 150)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Literally make them the same value.

[image: Scale]

Comment: How this value relate to object size? I have tried by change this value but nothing change.

Comment: That number is the number you need to apply to objects so that they match the UI scale. If you are having a problem, you need to supply more information.

Comment: @Tkaewkunha So I pulled up a blank Unity project and fiddled around. The setting I pointed out works a little differently than I thought, but I still don't have the problem you have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW2MS.png

Comment: Could you give me your canvas inspector and Hierarchy window?

Comment: I have try in blank project, There is no any problem. I think i did something wrong in my main project. Anyway, Thank you so much.

Comment: My canvas has all default values, the hierarchy is just a Canvas -> [Button, Cube]